# RETAG: unsolved-problems to open-problem

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I think "open-problem" (or simply "open") is nicer and more common.

**Update**: We now have open-problem $\leftarrow$ unsolved-problems

Comment: works for me. others ?

Comment: I agree with “open-problem.”  I do not see any reason to change it to “open,” though.

Comment: Agree with the renaming.  However, what is an "open problem"?  Does it include "problem that has been stated in the literature, and is widely known to be open" (which I think MO discourages)?

Comment: I am still seeing unsolved-problems on several questions?  The wiki does redirect, though.

Comment: I did a redirect but haven't merged - I was waiting to hear more about this.